# How to remove calc from conic-gradient code

Tags: css, background, gradient, css-gradients

How would this gradient code be written without `calc`?

That is all I am trying to figure out how to do. https://jsfiddle.net/gwrcep3q/

```css
.exitnew {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  --b: 7px;
  --c: green 90deg, blue 0;
  background: conic-gradient(from 90deg at var(--b) var(--b), var(--c)) calc(100% + var(--b)/2) calc(100% + var(--b)/2)/ calc(50% + var(--b)) calc(50% + var(--b));
  border: 5px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
```

```html
<button class="exitnew" type="button" aria-label="Close"></button>
```

Comment: Instead of var(--b) and var(--c) just write in their values - exactly as they are shown. I suggest that reading up on CSS and in particular CSS variables would be useful. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Comment: That does not replace calc in the code though, which is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I phrased that wrongly, misunderstood what the question was. If you don't want to use calc you can't mix % and px units so you'll have to decide on how to do it all in say % units. Can you say why you can't use calc as it is an obvious way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why are you insisting on removing `calc()`. You can make your code more lengthy by using 2 gradients if you are afraid of `calc()` but better learn something new:

```css
.exitnew {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background:
    linear-gradient(green 0 0),
    linear-gradient(green 0 0)
    blue;
  background-size:7px 100%,100% 7px;
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  border: 5px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
```

```html
<button class="exitnew" type="button" aria-label="Close"></button>
```

Comment: How come you removed the conic-gradient from it? It's not able to work with that property?